# Html tags are not rendering under if-else statements in Email Templates in kentico8

Tags: c#, kentico

I have a requirement to generate e-mails based on conditions. Here is the e-mail template:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial">
    <p>
      This is an automatic notification sent by Kentico. The following document is waiting for your approval. Please sign in to the Kentico administration interface and approve it.
    </p><br />
    {%if (2<3) { %}  
    <p>
      <b><i>This is Sent By : {%SentBy%}</i></b><br /><br />
      <a href={%siteurl%}>SiteURL</a><br />
      <br />
    </p>
    {% }else{%}
    <p>This is else Method</p>
    {%}#%}
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
EmailMessage msg = new CMS.EmailEngine.EmailMessage();
        EmailTemplateInfo etInfo = EmailTemplateProvider.GetEmailTemplate("Email", SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);
        if (etInfo != null)
        {
            MacroResolver mcr = MacroResolver.GetInstance();
            mcr.SetNamedSourceData("siteurl", "http://google.com/");
            mcr.SetNamedSourceData("SentBy", "admin");

            msg.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Both;
            msg.From = etInfo.TemplateFrom;
            msg.Recipients = "xyz@google.com";
            msg.Subject = etInfo.TemplateSubject;
            msg.Body = etInfo.TemplateText;
            msg.PlainTextBody = etInfo.TemplatePlainText;

            //Send Email..
            EmailSender.SendEmailWithTemplateText(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, msg, etInfo, mcr, true);

        }
```

When I send the e-mail it gets rendered as follows:

```
This is an automatic notification sent by Kentico. The following document is waiting for your approval. Please sign in to the Kentico administration interface and approve it.

    <p> <b><i>This is Sent By : admin</i></b><br /><br /> <a href=http://google.com/>SiteURL</a><br /> <br /> </p>
```

All HTML tags below the "if" condition are not being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get text with resolved macros you also need to call `ResolveMacros` method.

In your case it could be something like this:

```
        EmailMessage msg = new CMS.EmailEngine.EmailMessage();
        EmailTemplateInfo etInfo = EmailTemplateProvider.GetEmailTemplate("Email", SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);
        if (etInfo != null)
        {
            MacroResolver mcr = MacroResolver.GetInstance();
            mcr.SetNamedSourceData("siteurl", "http://google.com/");
            mcr.SetNamedSourceData("SentBy", "admin");

            msg.EmailFormat = EmailFormatEnum.Both;
            msg.From = etInfo.TemplateFrom;
            msg.Recipients = "xyz@google.com";
            msg.Subject = etInfo.TemplateSubject;
            msg.Body = mcr.ResolveMacros(etInfo.TemplateText);
            msg.PlainTextBody = mcr.ResolveMacros(etInfo.TemplatePlainText);

            //Send Email..
            EmailSender.SendEmailWithTemplateText(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, msg, etInfo, mcr, true);
        }
```

Notice the `mcr.ResolveMacros(etInfo.TemplateText)` code that I'm using.

Comment: Glad to hear that. In that case you can accept the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd add encode parameter to the macro:

```
{% some_macro_with_html_output|(encode)false %}
```

I'm not sure if it works with your type of record. Try to add it right before closing tag of else statement.